# Is there a less compiler that works on windows and has an interactive mode?

Tags: windows, less

I really like the sass -i command, it lets me compile bits of sass and see the result without having to run the whole file.  Is there a less compiler out there that has this same functionality? I'm on win7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2986204/139010

Comment: I'm not sure if an online compiler is exactly what you seek, but for "bits" of LESS, I use http://less2css.org/ all the time to see results.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WinLess](http://winless.org/)

WinLess is a Windows GUI for LESS.js. WinLess is a must-have for the webdeveloper who uses Windows. Its has online as well.

[Online LESS Compiler](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler)

good luck!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're looking for a "Fiddle for C/C++".

There's always codepad:

- http://codepad.org/

Or IdeaOne:

- http://ideone.com/

Comment: I think you've completely missed the question. The OP is looking for a [LESS](http://lesscss.org) compiler.

Comment: @Matt Ball - you're right - sorry :(  CLJ: have you tried WinLess: http://winless.org/?  There are provisions for both GUI and command line tools.

Comment: @paulsm4 I see the commadline tools, do you know if they have an interactive mode?